# python -m test results returns failure

Tags: python, pyenv

I'm a little concerned that I've messed something up after uninstalling Python 3.8.5 and reinstalling via pyenv. I am following [this guide](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) and when I try to test whether I have properly installed Python 3.8.5 by running `python -m test` I am getting a `Tests result: Failure` I am working with .zsh in iTERM2 on MacOS Catalina (if that helps).

I'm trying to neatly reinstall python etc. after my previous installations turned into a bit of a spaghetti heap, so I am using `pyenv` per recommendations across the web.

```
== Tests result: FAILURE ==

363 tests OK.

5 tests failed:
    test_import test_posix test_py_compile test_rlcompleter
    test_scriptpackages

36 tests skipped:
    test_al test_bsddb test_bsddb3 test_cd test_cl test_codecmaps_cn
    test_codecmaps_hk test_codecmaps_jp test_codecmaps_kr
    test_codecmaps_tw test_curses test_epoll test_gdb test_gdbm
    test_gl test_imgfile test_largefile test_linuxaudiodev test_msilib
    test_ossaudiodev test_poll test_py3kwarn test_smtpnet
    test_socketserver test_spwd test_startfile test_sunaudiodev
    test_timeout test_tk test_tools test_ttk_guionly test_urllib2net
    test_urllibnet test_winreg test_winsound test_zipfile64
2 skips unexpected on darwin:
    test_spwd test_tools

Total duration: 5 min 29 sec
Tests result: FAILURE
```

Comment: I just updated to ubuntu 20.04 so ran this test and got 9 errors. Yikes.

Comment: Uh oh. So what does this mean?

Comment: I hope it means the tests aren't worth crap. Except that's bad too. I've never tried this before so its going to take some time to see what level of panic is needed.

Comment: In my case I'm missing files the test expected to be there. They may be in a .deb I haven't installed. You could dig in and find the details of why it failed. If you are on windows, posix is likely to fail (although it should have been skipped, one would think).

Comment: Ok so it’s not necessarily a bad thing if the there are some failures in the test?

Comment: I'm not sure but am not worried. Its worth digging into more, but not worth loosing sleep over.