# Python successfully compiled by pyenv on Fedora 36 Linux, but fails tests

Tags: python, linux, fedora, pyenv

I am using `pyenv` to compile and install Python 3.10.5 for my user on hardware running Fedora 36.

Python compiles successfully, but when I run `python -m tests` I'm getting multiple failures ...

```
== Tests result: FAILURE ==                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                              
392 tests OK.                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                              
11 tests failed:                                                                                                              
    test_cmd_line_script test_compileall test_distutils test_imp                                                              
    test_import test_importlib test_inspect                                                                                   
    test_multiprocessing_main_handling test_py_compile test_runpy                                                             
    test_venv                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                              
24 tests skipped:                                                                                                             
    test_asdl_parser test_check_c_globals test_clinic test_curses                                                             
    test_dbm_gnu test_dbm_ndbm test_devpoll test_gdb test_kqueue                                                              
    test_msilib test_ossaudiodev test_smtpnet test_socketserver                                                               
    test_startfile test_tix test_tk test_ttk_guionly test_urllib2net                                                          
    test_urllibnet test_winconsoleio test_winreg test_winsound
    test_xmlrpc_net test_zipfile64

Total duration: 26 min 52 sec
Tests result: FAILURE
```

I've tried deleting the `~/.pyenv` directory and starting again from scratch. Installing penv using `git`, compiling and installing Python `pyenv install -v 3.10.5`, setting `global` to the new Python, and re-run the tests with the same failing results.

I tried performing the same steps on a virtual machine also running Fedora 36, and on the VM the tests run successfully ...

```
== Tests result: SUCCESS ==

403 tests OK.

24 tests skipped:
    test_asdl_parser test_check_c_globals test_clinic test_curses
    test_dbm_gnu test_dbm_ndbm test_devpoll test_gdb test_kqueue
    test_msilib test_ossaudiodev test_smtpnet test_socketserver
    test_startfile test_tix test_tk test_ttk_guionly test_urllib2net
    test_urllibnet test_winconsoleio test_winreg test_winsound
    test_xmlrpc_net test_zipfile64

Total duration: 27 min 25 sec
Tests result: SUCCESS
```

I saw a relevant post about test failure issue - [python -m test results returns failure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63462463) - but without resolution.

I'm trying to understand the difference in test results, if its something to be concerned about, and, if so, how to fix. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed now. Any further investigation is out of the scope of Stack Overflow and would also require a reproducible example from your side.

Comment: So even though the tests fail running on actual physical hardware, its nothing to be concerned about?